# Deploy to GIT from wercker

Tags: git, deployment, wercker

I'm using [wercker](http://wercker.com) to build my website with Grunt. The last build step of my build is to copy the contents of the `dist` folder to the `$WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR`.

For the deployment I would like to copy these contents to a subfolder of another (remote) repository. As I'm completely new to wercker I'm not sure how to do this and where to start (except for adding some deploy step in my wercker.yml). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to use the `scp` command in the deploy target and copy whatever you have the source  dir to the target box.
[This document can shed some more light](http://blog.wercker.com/2013/08/22/Simplifying-ssh-based-deployment.html) (search for `scp`).